# Suggested stack-based website for question about

Tags: discussion, questions

> This is part of a series of questions which focuses on a project called the Abstraction Project, which aims to abstract the concepts used in language design in the form of a framework.
>
> Another page associated to it related to structural typing can be viewed [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96229/is-structural-typing-in-a-hierarchical-model-necessary). The question related to ease of use can be viewed [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97124/how-easy-should-a-language-development-framework-be-to-use).

I have a question associated to the focus of stackoverflow; if someone was interested in writing a language framework and wanted to inquire about possible features, usability and so on.

Since it's not technically a question of 'how to', I wondered whether it would be an appropriate question to post.

The main thing I need assistance with is determining whether something I'm working on is simple enough to use for the Average Joe Programmer.  Granted a large portion of this is in the realm of subjectivity; however, there are likely objective views that can be added into this (if most people can't use something, at what point can you objectively record it.)  Further related to language features: if something's a bad idea, there can be objective reasons as to why it's a bad idea.

Focus on ease of code synthesis versus explicitly defining the nature of the code (action-based synthesis versus something like CodeDOM which requires explicitly defining the types that describe the actions/code.)

Suggestions, and directions, towards this are appreciated.

Comment: So, basically, your answer is the best place for it is multiple websites.
I suppose that makes sense given that each website has an intended goal.  Is it fine within the topics to maintain a generalized link or two to help connect the group of questions together in the case of providing context between them?

Comment: I think linking the questions is a great idea, and it also acknowledges that they are related but (hopefully) not duplicates of one another.  I wouldn't scatter things too much, but keeping with what's on topic from one site to another will help your chances of success.

Comment: If you'd prefer to submit your initial comment as an answer, that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking the issues down into smaller, addressable components is much better than trying to encompass what could be a huge field of inquiry in 1-2 questions.

A site like Programmers.SE would afford you more flexibility with the more conceptual questions, but read [the Good Subjective, Bad Subjective blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) to get an idea of the limits on this. If you already have some code in hand, check out [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), and of course look over their FAQ, too.

[Adapted from comment]